# Changing in the top of the browser using HTML (favicon)

Tags: html, favicon

How do you change the small image showed in a browsers tab when viewing image using HTML? Sorry, I am new to programming.

[image]

The small image is what I am talking about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it's called a [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon):

place the favicon.ico file in the www root and use the following code:

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

Comment: The closing slash of the link tag is missing: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

Comment: closing slash is just needed for xhtml :-)

Answer (score 3):

Insert the following line in `<head>` tag

`<link href="Images/tsp1.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />`

Replace `Images/tsp1.png` with an image of your choice, make it somting like a 16x16 image

Answer (score 2):

This is the Favicon. Have a look at the whikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Answer (score 1):

Have an image in ico format with name favicon.ico in the root of your site. Search for favicon.ico for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.example.com/myicon.ico">
```