# how to attach company logo in Web Application URL in the address bar

Tags: asp.net

Please tell me how to add company logo with web application url address bar

Answer (score 4):

Add `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">` to `<head />` and put favicon.ico to your website.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a [favicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531976/changing-in-the-top-of-the-browser-using-html) (StackOverFlow Thread)

Answer (score 0):

Please create a small image and create a link and paste in to your head section  to  ........... when you open your site then this icon show you on top .........Thanks.