# How to put a bookmark icon (favicon) in website

Tags: html, css, wordpress

See the small logo/icon in the tab when you open any website in any browser?:

[image]
**How can I put such logo/icon on my wordpress blog?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing in the top of the browser using HTML (favicon)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531976/changing-in-the-top-of-the-browser-using-html-favicon)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways,

the first is use this plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shockingly-simple-favicon/

Or, if you really want to learn how it works. Open your theme folder (normally under wp-content -> themes -> your theme name) and then normally in the header.php file there is everythign that happens in the head of your pages.

Any where in the `<head></head>` place the following code...

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

Where /favicon, is the link to your favicon.ico.

To easily make a favicon, use the following link.

http://www.favicon.co.uk/

Hope this helps you learn how to do it and what the actual plugin does for you :)

Comment: i have put favicon.ico in my root directory http://shareprogrammingtips.com/favicon.ico then i have installed that plugin still i am not getting that logo ...

Comment: Then you are not linking to it correctly. This doesnt warrent the retraction of the answer status?

Comment: in chrome its works but in firefox it didnt show...how linking ?

Comment: It will take some time to update in Firefox due to its caching - its normal do not worry :)

Comment: oh then its fine...i am embedded engineer i dont know too much about this all stuff so..anyz thanks

Comment: No worries. Glad to have been able to help you out :)

Answer (score 6):

This is called a `favicon`. You link to it in the head section of your HTML.

You can read more about it here: http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

And view a list of Wordpress plugins that do the work for you here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/favicon

Answer (score 1):

Use plungin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shockingly-simple-favicon/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put the image into a file named `favicon.ico` in your website's root directory (like `www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico`). Browsers request this file when a user visits your site and will show it in the tab or bookmarks. You can find more info on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) or even use http://www.favicon.cc/ to help you design the icon.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

1. In your template `header.php` file, you have to add the favicon code: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`
2. or, you just put the favicon.ico into your www root. Apache has a configuration setting which will load this as default.